# Alpine Js does not sync data for x-text and x-model, if used in a loop on table row

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I am trying to loop over employees array and I want show employee salary and an input field to edit employee salary. The problem is that Alpine does not sync data from input field to the text element.
Example:

```
<tbody>
    <template x-for="employee in employees">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input x-model="employee.basic_salary">
            </td>
            <td x-text="employee.basic_salary"></td>
        </tr>
    </template>
</tbody>

<script>
function data() {
    return {
        employees: [
            {id:1, basic_salary: 6000},
            {id:2, basic_salary: 7000},
        ]
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

`template` needs to have 1 direct element descendent. So wrapping it's contents in a `div` should do the trick.

```html
    <template x-for="user in users">
      <div>
        <p x-text="user.name"></p>
        <input type="text" x-model="user.name">
      </div>
    </template>
```

I believe your markup would've caused alpine to log a warning.

Comment: Ok, Thanks i will try out this.

Comment: This is what i have in a real project. I am using a <tr> instead of (I have datatables on this table) If I add a <div> before <tr> It will destroy datatables data and does not show the rows.
`<template x-for="employee in employees">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" x-bind:name="`basic_salary[${employee.id}]`" x-model="employee.basic_salary">
        </td>
        
        <td>
            <span x-text="employee.basic_salary"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>`

Comment: Yeah that's because `div` breaks tables, if you wrap everything inside of the template in `<tr>` does that not work?

Comment: Like `<template><tr><template>other stuff</template></tr></template>` ?. No, that does not help.

Comment: `<template><tr>other stuff</tr></template>`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to move the  inside the the  and it works but It breaks the table, so it does not work as expected:(
Here is what i tried:

```
<template x-for="employee in employees">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input x-model="employee.basic_salary">
            </td>
            <td x-text="employee.basic_salary"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</template>

<script>
function data() {
    return {
        employees: [
            {id:1, basic_salary: 6000},
            {id:2, basic_salary: 7000},
        ]
    }
}
</script>
```

One should never put a loop before `<tbody>`

Answer (score 0):

Follow @Hugos advice.
I had the same issue. I ended up using div set to grid. you can set up the column width using template grid columns[image]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33604397)

Comment: Yeah I just re-read the question I guess I was caught up in the table markup since the OP already said its works but the table breaks. I will revert if its still unanswered when I have some time